# Hackerrank problem: several for loops in a list comprehension

Tags: python

I'm resolving a problem in hackerrank, have a look:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/between-two-sets/problem

I m trying to have one line of code

so I tried to create a list, that go through all the integers between the last integer of the first array and the first integer of the second array with `range (a[-1],b[0])`

than I want to apply the 2 conditions with `if i%j==0 and x%i==0` with j and x the integers in the 2 arrays a and b `for j in a for x in b` 
the `set()` retrieve the duplicates

```
def getTotalX(a, b):
    inbetween = set([i for i in range (a[-1],b[0]) for j in a for x in b if i%j==0 and x%i==0])
    return (inbetween)
```

output `[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 12, 12]`

the code act as this: on each `i`, it compares it for the first `j` of the loop, add the `i` in the array if it correspond to the condition, then compare the same `i` with the next iteration of the `for j in a`loop and add again the same `i` in the array if it correspond

how could I write the code to compare one `i` to all of the `j` in the array `a`? can I write it on the same line?

Comment: In general *I m trying to have one line of code* and *is it comprehensible?* are at odds as statements. Using one line of code is a good way to make your code difficult to read and debug. My suggestion would be to split it into many lines. At least use line breaks in the list comprehension.

Comment: I find hard to understand what you need. The `for`s in the code you have written seem to be correct. For debugging, you may want to change `set([` to `([(i, j, x, b)` and see the output. If you still can't figure out, please post the full Python script, its actual output and its expected output.

Comment: Doesn't `range (a[-1],b[0])` assume that (1) `a` and `b` are sorted ascending and (2) `a[-1]` is less than `b[0]`. I don't see either of assumptions stated in the question.

Comment: You might look into the `any` and `all` functions for more readable code.

Comment: To add to @Dan's initial statement, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Prune says, `any` and `all` can make code both shorter, and in my opinion more readable (than the alternative with `break` and things).

```
def getTotalX(a, b):
    return {i for i in range(a[-1], b[0])
               if all(i % j == 0 for j in a)
              and all(x % i == 0 for x in b)}

getTotalX([2, 6], [24, 36]) # {6, 12}
```

Comment: Both `all` expression here should be broken out into sensibly named functions. Also `x`, `j` and `i` are dubious variable name choices. Especially `j` which is hiding complex numbers now. Also, you should wrap the set in `len` as the correct answer is `2`, the number of included numbers.

Comment: You are just being unreasonable now. Which one of `number_can_be_divided_by_all_in_array(num, array_a)` and `all(i % j == 0 for j in a)` is easier to understand? In my opinion it is actually the latter. Plus, the former approach is more liable to hide bugs as readers are forced to believe the English description, or break the flow of reading by going to check the function.

Comment: you think it's easier to debug a single line of code than a simple function? If there is an error, how will you know which `all` statement it's in? Also how about `are_all_factors_of(num, list_a)` and `is_factor_of_all(num, list_b)`?

Comment: @Dan The first one translates in my head to "`num` are all factors of `list_a`". Of course that doesn't make sense in English, but it takes a few moments to adjust (disclaimer: I'm not a native speaker of English). Besides, how am I supposed to know which way the arguments go except by looking at the function definition?

Comment: @Dan In my opinion, once something is simple enough to be written in one line of code, the problem is not usually debugging it, but realizing that it has a bug in the first place. And that is certainly harder when the actual code is hidden away in a faraway function definition.

Comment: @Dan "If there is an error, how will you know which `all` statement it's in?" If you cannot tell at a glance by looking at the actual code, you can always print it out.

Comment: What on earth is a faraway function? Your IDE should take you to a function definition with a simple hotkey. And the same for the params. I'm just making suggestions that a new programmer like the OP would benefit from learning early. Putting a lot of logic in a single line is a bad idea. Remember, future people will have to come back to this code to maintain it long after anyone remembers writing the specific line.

Comment: "you can always print it out." how? By writing extra code? With a function you'd just know immediately based on the error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195194/discussion-between-imperishable-night-and-dan).

Comment: Random thought: "<Something> is easy/hard to read" is a self-fulfilling prophecy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and sorry for the confusion in the post.

Input:

```
[2,4]
[16,32,96]
```

Output:
`3`

Explanation:
the output is the number of integers between those 2 arrays that satisfy these condition:

1- The elements of the first array are all factors of the integer being considered

2- The integer being considered is a factor of all elements of the second array

so the output here is 3 because there are 3 integers that satisfy these conditions:
4, 8 and 16

for example for `4`:

1- `4%2=0` and `4%4 =0`

2- `16%4=0` and `32%4=0` and `96%4=0`

so thanks for your help I submitted this and it worked!

```
def getTotalX(a, b):
    return len([i for i in range(a[-1],b[0]+1) if all(i%j==0 for j in a) and all(x%i==0 for x in b)])
```

thanks for your help! I guess I have to come with better naming than i, j, x for bigger code

Comment: I know some people would disapprove of the use of one-letter variable names altogether, but I think they are great as long as they are used correctly. I usually reserve `i`, `j`, and to a lesser extent `k` for indices; for the actual values I tend to use `x`, `y`, `z`. Therefore I would probably use `z`, `x`, `y` instead of `i`, `j`, `x` (using `x` and `y` because they correspond to `a` and `b` nicely).